# How to create multiple unique data points in Mongoose schema?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, indexing, mongoose

I'm using express and with mongoose/mongo db and have a user document with 2 data points that I want to be unique (email and username). My problem is that my sign-up process is multiple steps so email is saved first then in the next step username is saved. I have a bug where if a user is between steps 1 and 2, no other users can sign up because I get the error saying that the username or email they try to save isn't unique. If the user that was between steps 1 and 2 finished then the other user can create an email and it works perfectly. What I am currently doing is compound indexing and somehow associates the2 fields. I need a solution where mongo db returns an error if it tries to save the field but there is an already existing identical piece of data in that field for another user. I already do my own checking to make sure it is unique by searching for that email and allowing the save if the search returned nothing. The problem with this is that it's async and a user could potentially submit the same email or username twice at the same time and it would create. I want to use mongo unique indexes for both fields individually (not linked in any way) so that mongo will return an error if not unique thus solving this edge case. What am I doing wrong here? How do I make these fields unique but in no way associated with one another? Here is the gist of my code:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 email: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  trim: true
},
 username: {
  type: String,
  required: false,
  trim: true
}
})

UserSchema.index({
  email: 1,
  username: 1
}, {unique: true});
```

Comment: `username` is not required but you want to use it in a composite key? Are you sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is due to the fact that you have not created a `sparse` or `partial` index for the `username` field.

**Do not do this**

```
// Mongoose Schema Version
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 email: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  unique: true,
  trim: true
},
 username: {
  type: String,
  required: false,
  unique: true,
  trim: true
}
})

// Mongo Version
db.users.createIndex({ email: 1 }, { unique: true });
db.users.createIndex({ username: 1}, { unique: true });

// Mongoose Verion (Users is a Schema)
UserSchema.index({ email: 1 }, { unique: true });
UserSchema.index({ username: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

You will have the following issue:

1. INSERT `{email: 'me@email.com'}`
2. Attempt to INSERT `{email: 'you@email.com'}` -- FAIL!

In MongoDB you have two records trying to set `username` to `null`. Whether they set it explicitly or implicitly (by omitting `username`) that index will fail to store two `null` items as they collide. That is why if you set individual indexes for the fields the DB gets *stuck* until a user completes step one, which allows another user to enter step one and submit a `null` username, but once again blocks the db. It is possible to solve this with a compound index, however that will cause other issues such as users registering the same email to two usernames.

**Do this for MongoDB newer than 3.2**

> Partial indexes only index the documents in a collection that meet a specified filter expression. By indexing a subset of the documents in a collection, partial indexes have lower storage requirements and reduced performance costs for index creation and maintenance.

```
// Mongo Version
db.users.createIndex({ email: 1 }, { unique: true });
db.users.createIndex({ username: 1}, { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { username: { $exists: true } } });

// Mongoose Verion (Users is a Schema)
UserSchema.index({ email: 1 }, { unique: true });
UserSchema.index({ username: 1 }, { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { username: { $exists: true } } });
```

**Do this instead for MongoDB older than 3.2**

> Sparse indexes only contain entries for documents that have the indexed field, even if the index field contains a null value. The index skips over any document that is missing the indexed field. The index is “sparse” because it does not include all documents of a collection. By contrast, non-sparse indexes contain all documents in a collection, storing null values for those documents that do not contain the indexed field.

```
// Mongoose Schema Version
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 email: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  unique: true,
  trim: true
},
 username: {
  type: String,
  required: false,
  unique: true,
  sparse: true,
  trim: true
}
})

// Mongo Version
db.users.createIndex({ email: 1 }, { unique: true });
db.users.createIndex({ username: 1}, { unique: true, sparse: true });

// Mongoose Verion (Users is a Schema)
UserSchema.index({ email: 1 }, { unique: true });
UserSchema.index({ username: 1 }, { unique: true, sparse: true });
```

> Changed in version 3.2: Starting in MongoDB 3.2, MongoDB provides the option to create partial indexes. Partial indexes offer a superset of the functionality of sparse indexes. If you are using MongoDB 3.2 or later, partial indexes should be preferred over sparse indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose Provides you the ability to have unique fields.
And it returns the error when these conditions are not matched.

For eg:
    `E11000 duplicate key error index in mongodb mongoose`

You can update your code like:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 email: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  unique: true,
  trim: true
},
 username: {
  type: String,
  required: false,
  unique: true,
  trim: true
}
})
```

Comment: This answer will cause the issue the OP was commenting about.